# SharePoint 2010 web frontend

Tags: sharepoint-2010, load, load-balancing, web-frontend

i had a Sharepoint 2010 farm with two web frontend servers (Medium Size), one of them is displaying some weird results, i was wondering if theres a way to see from wicht of my server frontend a getting that error. I mean, if a had to servers ServerFrontEnd1 and ServerFrontEnd2 when i open the Site, i would like to know from wicth of those servers i getting the response. (Load Balancing)

Who the Load Balance its done in Sharepoint 2010.

And also, who can i clear the cache of my farm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the file system on each front end, you could create multiple images containing front end server numbers. Give each image the same file name (i.e., frontend.jpg) and save it to the same path on each server:

[SharePoint Root]\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\frontend.jpg

Then you can always tell which front end your request is hitting simply by visiting the URL mycompany.com/_layouts/images/frontend.jpg.

I just blogged about this:
http://www.dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/which-sharepoint-front-end-server-am-i-hitting/

Best of luck!

Comment: This is really smart, and i thing its a good practice to do it in QA enviroment, thanks for this post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check the Main Server Log Files which is hosting the core functionality of sharepoint and controlling all farm. there you can see which site and server is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a solution that tackles this exact problem by taking advantage of delegate controls

http://spservername.codeplex.com/